# How do you calculate the "true" chemical potential in classical density functional theory?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, chemical-potential, density-functional-theory

In classical density functional theory, one traditionally calculates the chemical potential by taking the variational derivative,
\begin{equation}
\mu_{i} = \frac{\delta F}{\delta \rho_{i}}
\end{equation}
of the Helmholtz free energy
\begin{equation}
F[\rho] = \int d\textbf{r} f(\rho, \nabla \rho, ...) \textrm{.}
\end{equation}

However, this is not directly analogous to the chemical potential in classical thermodynamics. In the latter theory, the chemical potential is defined as a partial derivative with respect to the number of moles,
\begin{equation}
\hat{\mu}_{i} = \frac{\partial A}{\partial n_{i}}
\end{equation}
where $A$ is the homogeneous Helmholtz free energy analogous to $F$.
Importantly, $n_{i}$ is an *extrinsic* quantity (e.g. $n_{i} = \rho_{i} V$, where $V$ is the system volume). This means that $\mu_{i}$, defined in DFT is actually analogous to the derivative
\begin{equation}
\mu_{i} = \frac{\partial A}{\partial \rho_{i}}
\end{equation}

How then does one obtain the actual analogue,
\begin{equation}
\hat{\mu}_{i} = \frac{\delta F}{\delta n_{i}}
\end{equation}
to the traditional chemical potential?
Is this generalization correct? If so, how does one go about computing such a quantity when the number of moles $n_{i}$ is now itself a functional of the density,
\begin{equation}
n_{i} = \int d\textbf{r} \rho_{i}(\textbf{r})
\end{equation}

Aside:

- It is clear that $\partial A/\partial \rho_{i}$ is related to the difference between chemical potentials for an incompressible, multicomponent system, e.g. http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.83.061602. Because of this, it is sometimes called an "exchange" chemical potential, e.g. https://doi.org/10.1039/C6SM02839J.
- There is also a connection between the exchange chemical potentials and the osmotic pressure, $\pi = \partial A/\partial V$. It is not clear to me how one can calculate the osmotic pressure from a functional either, since it is also an extrinsic quantity.

Related:

- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3016507/
- https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3697883/

Comment: In case this question does not attract many answers (I don't think there are many computational chemists/materials people here), I would try posting it here: https://materials.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @Godzilla123. I didn't realize there was a materials forum. Posted: https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/how-do-you-calculate-the-true-chemical-potential-in-classical-density-function

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a detailed answer; hopefully I can come back and answer it more fully later. However, here is a simple explanation that might help.

Instead of taking the functional derivative of the Helmholtz free energy, you can consider taking the functional derivative the free energy *density*. Essentially, this is just taking the thermodynamic derivative

$$ \hat{\mu_i}=\frac{\partial A}{\partial N_i} $$
and dividing both the numerator and denominator by the volume $V$.